# Firma de apps Google Play

Tags: android, flutter

Buenas se me presenta el siguiente problema. Quiero subir un apk a la play console pero me dice que si o si necesito subir el  bundle; bueno ya hice el build bundle y todo eso. Ahora cuando quiero subir ese archivo me dice que tengo que estar registrado en la firma de apps, cuando entro a esa solapa me sale lo siguiente:

[image]

La primera opcion la descarto trate de hacerla siguiendo los pasos de la documentacion pero en android studio me aparece deshabilitada la opcion que dice la guia asi que no puedo continuar.

la segunda opcion la descarto porque no tengo almacen de claves.

y la tercera opcion (la que esta abierta en la imagen) es la que quiero usar pero no sé como, me da el codigo ese y no sé dónde usarlo ni que hacer con él.
(mi app esta hecha en flutter, no sé si influye en su ayuda )

Comment: El bundle es opcional. Pará firmar tus aplicaciones podes leer esto
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419

Comment: Justamente esa es la documentación que seguí y no me salió

Comment: Creo que la manera más fácil de hacerlo es con un almacen de llaves puedes mostrar la opción que te sale deshabilitada